# Customizing New tab button in Google Chrome for Desktop PC

Tags: google-chrome, desktop-computer

In Google Chrome (for PC) when I click the new tab button, is there anyway to get the Apps page instead of New tab page?

I am hoping i could do this (if at all possible) by fiddling with the preferences file.

I know this might be an odd choice, but just curious. If i could do this, i will be very pleased.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a setting for this in about://flags but it seems to have been removed in the latest update

there are extensions that provide this functionality though such as 
[new tab redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna/related)

that will redirect your new tab page to what you set it to

Comment: Thanks a million..

Was searching for this for a while now..
Never knew what to search for..!

This is all i am looking for. :)

Comment: Great stuff, can you flag this as answered then, thanks